# How to pass an array from an api as props to another component

Tags: reactjs

I am making an api call which returns me an array of Usernames. I am calling the api in a Navbar component and am sending the data returned by the api to another component as props. When I console.log(this.state.Name) in Navbar it gives the whole array having usernames in the console, but when i receive the array in the other SearchedUser componenet and console.log() the recieved prop it gives me undefined in the console. Can Anyone tell whats wrong.

----------------------------------Navbar Component----------------------------

```
     class Navbar extends Component{

     constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        name:'',
        Name:[],
    }
     this.GetUserData=this.GetUserData.bind(this);
}

    GetUserData=()=>{
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/data/searchuser?Name=${this.state.name}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data=> this.setState({Name:data.datad}))
.catch(err=>console.log(err));}

        render()
{
    console.log(this.state.Name);
    return(
        <Router>
          <Link to={'/SearchedUser'}> 
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.GetUserData}><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
         </Link>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContent} />
                <Route path='/Profile' component={Profile}/>
                <Route path='/SearchedUser' render={(props)=> <SearchedUser {...props} UserName={ [this.state.Name]}/>}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>)  }}
```

--------------------------------SearchedUser Component------------------------

```
    import React from 'react'
class SearchedUser extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
    Name: props.UserName
}
    }

    render(){
console.log(this.state.Name);
return(
    <div>         
    </div>
     )
    }
    }
export default SearchedUser;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use componentWillReceiveProps to update the state

```
            import React from 'react'
            class SearchedUser extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {
                        Name:[]
                    }
                }

            /** When the SearchedUser component does anything with the new props,
            * componentWillReceiveProps is called, with the next props as the argument */


            componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

                /** Update  state**/
                if (nextProps.UserName !== this.props.UserName) {
                    this.setState({
                        Name: nextProps.UserName
                    });
                }

            }

                render() {
                    console.log(this.state.Name);
                    return ( <
                        div >
                        <
                        /div>
                    )
                }
            }
            export default SearchedUser;
```

Comment: Yes i just did that. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 
`console.log(this.props.UserName);` 
inside the `render()` in **SearchedUser** Component.

Because you are trying to get the **username from the constructor** and by default the **search component** will be getting **`null`** value in the `props.username`

The `props.username` will only get the new value only after the fetch response has been received.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with 2 changes like:

`[this.state.Name]` > `this.state.Name` as the first one outputs an array with single entry like `['sara']`:

```
<SearchedUser {...props} UserName={this.state.Name}/>}
```

Another thing, in the constructor of NavBar component:

```
 this.state={
        name:'',
        Name:'',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

dude you need to access `props` by `this.props.propsName` in class component.

```js
//SearchedUser component

import React from 'react'
class SearchedUser extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state={
        Name: this.props.UserName
      }
   }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>         
      </div>
     )
   }
 }
 
export default SearchedUser;
```